# React native custom internet phone call

Tags: react-native

I have a 3 part question from important to less important:

Does someone know if there is a package to do phone calls trough the internet as Whatsapp and Facebook do?

Would it even be possible to do it without a phone number?
For example, only knowing someone's device id.

[image]

And can you even make your "ring page" custom? So adding functionalities while calling.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. There are plenty of ways to attack this but I would recommend using a React Native wrapper for Twilio (https://github.com/hoxfon/react-native-twilio-programmable-voice).

```
   import TwilioVoice from 'react-native-twilio-programmable-voice'

// ...

// initialize the Programmable Voice SDK passing an access token obtained from the server.
// Listen to deviceReady and deviceNotReady events to see whether the initialization succeeded.
async function initTelephony() {
    try {
        const accessToken = await getAccessTokenFromServer()
        const success = await TwilioVoice.initWithToken(accessToken)
    } catch (err) {
        console.err(err)
    }
}
 // iOS Only
function initTelephonyWithUrl(url) {
    TwilioVoice.initWithTokenUrl(url)
    try {
        TwilioVoice.configureCallKit({
            appName:       'TwilioVoiceExample',                  // Required param
            imageName:     'my_image_name_in_bundle',             // OPTIONAL
            ringtoneSound: 'my_ringtone_sound_filename_in_bundle' // OPTIONAL
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.err(err)
    }
```

For that approach I believe you have to have a phone number but you can build out the ui however you like.

If you are not into  the Twilio approach, you can use pure JS libraries to do the trick such as [SipJS](https://sipjs.com/).

There are also tutorials on Youtube which can lead you through the process like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLPueAdj52k).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you Voximplant, https://voximplant.com/docs/references/articles/quickstart,
it's easy to use and has clear documentation.

Comment: Hello @Moein I am trying VoxImplant, could you please tell how to test calls? let's say I want to automate a call on my phone and record it, I tried it's step but I didn't get it using this docs https://voximplant.com/docs/references/websdk/voximplant/client#call, where I passed my phone-number as argument in call() in Javascript.

Comment: VoxImplant has a demo for react native, https://github.com/voximplant/react-native-demo . you can clone this demo and find almost everything, for more detail you can find everything on documentation. as I remember you most create an account on Voximplant then create two user.after that install this demo on two devices and log in with user names which you create on Voximplant panel. then with a user name, you can make a call with users together.

Comment: Thanks @Moein, for quick reply. I will try it using two device. Should i purchase new number for both devices or any other option is available there?

Comment: your welcome. I am not sure, but I think you need to assign a number to each user but I am not sure to check it on documentation.